# Passing ajax callback on typeahead.js source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeahead.js

I'm using jQuery 2.1.4 and trying to modify Twitter typeahead.js 0.11.1 to accept an ajax request as a source. 
When I run the page from the local file system `file:///C:/...`, it works as expected, the error function is returned and the suggestion `noData` appears, but when I try to run the page directly from the server or even jsfiddle, the ajax success or error function are returned but the suggestions don't appear. The callback doesn´t seem to be working.

Do you think it is something related to the callback or the ajax request is being used improperly?

Below is my code:

HTML

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Names" id="tah1">
```

Javascript

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    name: 'userNames',
    source: 
        function findMatches(q, callback) {
            console.log('q: ' + q);
            var soapEnv =
                "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> "
                    + "<soap:Body>"
                        + "<ResolvePrincipals xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>"
                            + "<principalKeys>"
                            + "<string>" + q + "</string>"
                            + "</principalKeys>"
                            + "<principalType>All</principalType>"
                            + "<addToUserInfoList>true</addToUserInfoList>"
                        + "</ResolvePrincipals>"
                    + "</soap:Body>"
                + "</soap:Envelope>"    

            $.ajax({
                url: "www./_vti_bin/People.asmx?op=ResolvePrincipals",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: soapEnv,
                success: function(data){
                        console.log('ajax request successful');
                        callback(data);
                    },
                error: function(data){
                        console.log('ajax request error');
                        var errorValues = ['noData'];
                        callback(errorValues);
                    },
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/ResolvePrincipals"
            });
        }
});
```

I also created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathro/x61mbruw/).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's about cross domain request:

```
 $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "www./_vti_bin/People.asmx?op=ResolvePrincipals",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: soapEnv,
    success: function(data){
        console.log('ajax request successful');
        callback(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('ajax request error');
        var errorValues = ['noData'];
        callback(errorValues);
    },
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/ResolvePrincipals"
});
```

Use the options "crossDomain" and set it at true. Don't work on JSFiddle but your url is not reachable.

Comment: For sure this code will return a "crossDomain" issue because it is making a request to a url not reachable, but this is not the real problem, because at my server I'm having the same problem and there is no "crossDomain" there. I would like to receive the typeahead suggestions, when the request is successful or an error is returned.

Comment: there is a tip at line 10852 if u had this line `console.log(syncCalled)` don't know why your code is a bit a mess sorry here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x61mbruw/10/)

Comment: Thanks GuillaumeL, it worked, but I still don't understand what happened. Why adding callback2?

Comment: It's a realy good question and i don't know your callback is always call but it's shortcuted if syncCalled isn't true. Also i missunderstand this line `!syncCalled && sync([]);` and i didn't find out the mecanics of DataSet class so i'll need to work on it if i got some times.